# Shortest way to get a certain IP from ifconfig

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to isolate the IP of a certain linux interface using a single command over `ifconfig` to use it as a parameter in a command.

The following command is working:

```
ifconfig | grep -A1 docker | grep inet | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

but I wonder if there is a shorter and better way to do it.

---

**Important**: It must work with any european language configuration. For instance, the Spanish output for `ifconfig` looks like:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 02:42:b2:ff:14:5b  
          Direc. inet:172.17.0.1  Difus.:0.0.0.0  Másc:255.255.0.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::42:b2ff:feff:145b/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:12569 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:32629 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:698734 (698.7 KB)  TX bytes:46670727 (46.6 MB)

enp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW f0:bf:97:57:17:17  
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupción:18 

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:3681 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:3681 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:343046 (343.0 KB)  TX bytes:343046 (343.0 KB)
```

Comment: there are 2 matches for `inet` in `docker` section: `inet:172.17.0.1 ...` and `inet6: ...`. Which one should remain?

Comment: You can get only the information relevant to a desired interface with `ifconfig <interface>`, so if you want only the output for interface docker0, `ifconfig docker0` will be easier to use to parse later.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just one in my case, but just in case it should show the first one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ifconfig docker |grep -oP 'inet:\K[^ ]+'
172.17.0.1
```

Using `-P` flag of grep to enable `perl` regex and look around.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex:

```
ifconfig docker | awk '/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/{print $2}'
```

If the machine is linux you can use

```
hostname -i
```

Answer (score 0):

With single **awk** process:

```
ifconfig docker0 | awk '/inet:/{ print substr($2,6); exit }'
```

- `substr($2,6)` - extracting IP address from the 2nd field starting from the 6th char (i.e. from `inet:172.17.0.1` --> `172.17.0.1`)

---

The output will be (in your case):

```
172.17.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **`ip`** command, whose output is intended to be machine-readable:

```
ip -o -br -4 addr show dev docker0
```

We'll want to extract from the third set of spaces until the `/24`:

```
ip_addr=$(ip -o -br -4 addr show dev docker0  | tr -s ' /' '\t\t' | cut -f3)
```